# php ternary operator giving an error

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

In PHP, if I have a ternary like this:

```
$my_thing = $this->myAttribute ? $this->myAttribute : "No attribute was set.";
```

can it be abbreviated like this?

```
$my_thing = $this->myAttribute ?: "No attribute was set."
```

I thought I remembered PHP supporting this in its ternaries, but now I'm getting an error.

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: It can be shortened like that, but if `$this->myAttribute` does not exist you will still get a notice. What does "getting an error" mean exactly?

Comment: "but now I'm getting an error" --- so why didn't you share it? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: [Only 5.3+](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's supported in PHP 5.3 and up. From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.